# Scikit-learn Classification Models: Can I use the parameter "class_weight" too penalize a class?

Tags: python, c, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier to build a classification model. The Data contains two balanced classes. example:

```
target = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0] #1 & 0 appear four times each
```

In the real world use case of the model an incorrect prediction of "1" is more costly than an incorrect prediction of 0. To solve for this, can I use class_weight parameter to force the model to penalize incorrect predictions of 1 more?

When I test the parameter(`class_weight={0:2,1:1}`) I get these desired effect, but i'm not sure if it's considered the correct way to approach this problem. Changing the probability threshold for a "1" prediction is another approach I was considering.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not about general advice on ML methodology; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That said, your question maybe on topic in [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).